# How to use iPhone 6 back up on iPhone 4s?

Tags: ios

My iPhone 6 broke down and I've tried to use latest backup on my old 4s with no luck.
Is there any way I can use it for my old 4s?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the 4s is an iOS version behind:

If the iPhone 6, was/is on iOS 10/11(how to check it https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201685), there’re no way to do this, if not, try update the iPhone 4s to iOS 9.3.5 (how to update https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204), and then retry restoring the iPhone 4s from your backup.

Comment: Thanks Harcher,
I tried everything with no luck. My iPhone 6 had the latest iOS update and the max update you can use on the 4s is 9.3.5.

Comment: Are there any data you must have is it all “nice to have”?

Comment: Remember, most people have there iPhone set up so contacts, notes and maybe photos are synchronized over iCloud, outside of the backups...